# Regex. I want everything BUT a specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, capture

I have data that looks this:

```
Key:         [36;1m2848761038914979188[0m
Partition:   0
Offset:      33443
Timestamp:   2022-09-27 15:57:57.693 -0400 EDT
Key:         [36;1m2039734487331374643[0m
Partition:   0
Offset:      33444
Timestamp:   2022-09-27 17:26:31.477 -0400 EDT
Key:         [36;1m2868926969028805951[0m
Partition:   0
Offset:      33445
Timestamp:   2022-09-27 17:41:31.473 -0400 EDT
Key:         [36;1m2936812472746641386[0m
Partition:   0
Offset:      33446
Timestamp:   2022-09-27 18:02:23.803 -0400 EDT
```

I want a regex to match EVERYTHING BUT the numbers in between `[36;1m` and  `[0m`. How do I capture this? I don't want to regex match the numbers... I want everything BUT the numbers (I want this so I can delete everything but the numbers in my text editor).

this regex isn't good enough: `(^|\[)(?!36;1m)[^\[]*`:

Comment: Be clearer about what you actually want to do with it afterwards - "I want everything BUT the numbers **so I can delete everything else** " - what do you want the output to be, and what will you do with it?

Comment: sorry I want a regex to match everything but the numbers

Comment: You want to match everything but the numbers, and then delete everything but the numbers -- how about a regex that matches only the numbers, and keep only the matches? Then throw that at `grep -o` or similar and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the supported regex flavor, but matching all chars except the numbers between `[36;1m` and `[0m`

```
(?<=\[36;1m)\d+(?=\[0m)(*SKIP)(*F)|.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZNx9KR/1)

Or use a capture group 1 to use that in the replacement, and match any other character:

```
\[36;1m(\d+)\[0m|.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tkz7WH/1)

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you overcomplicating this? It sounds like this is enough:

```
\[36;1m(\d+)\[0m
```

Comment: The OP stated they want to match everything *except* the numbers in between `[36;1m` and `[0m`. That's the only thing this pattern matches. This effectively does the opposite of what the OP is asking.

Comment: What does it mean to capture everything but the numbers? Isn't it the same as matching those numbers and replacing them with empty string?

Comment: Fair point but that's not really what the OP asked for and your answer doesn't explain that approach.

Comment: okay how do I match everything but this pattern

Comment: @Jwan622 can you answer our questions first?

Comment: sorry by capture I mean... match. I just need a regex that will match everything but the numbers

Comment: @Jwan622 I don't think this kind of negative matching goes along with how regex works. Instead, how about matching all the numbers and copy-pasting them? It works in Sublime Text, so should work in your text editor too.